# wait for the processes

Tags: fork

I have a question on fork(). If my program takes only command line arguments, a number of child processes to spawn.  Each child process sleeps for a random number of seconds and then exits.  The main process should exit once a majority of the children have exited.  How should the code wait for the processes?  why the choice is smart choice in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use the wait() call.  This waits for any child to exit.  All you have to do is loop calling wait() until more than half the children have exited.